# Can not access the brake switch cold wire for my electric brake controller install. is there an alternative access to cold side wire of brake switch?

Tags: wire, cold

I have a 1997 Chevy 1500 Suburban, that I am hooking an electric trailer brake controller in.

I have tried everything to get to the brake switch, so I can tie in my red wire to the cold wire side of the brake switch.
But my hands are too big to get to the brake switch.
Is there an alternative access point to cold side wire of brake switch, other than at the brake switch?

Answer (score 0):

So for a trailer brake controller, that wire will be available at either rear light or even from front to rear.

If this is just for a signal then a direct connection will be fine, check to see if a fuse is suggested.